# Old anime people trapped in a computer

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, computers

I need help identifying one old anime that was about people getting trapped inside a computer.

I don't remember much about it but I remember that there was a mad scientist that put himself on purpose inside a computer. Then he was able to control the computer and somehow the computer was able to trap other people making them play games to survive. For example, I remember a scene where a man had to play a Pac-man like game and had to avoid being eaten (but he was eaten eventually).

Another thing I remember is that there was a guard dressed in a black and yellow uniform, and he was making sure that all the prisoners were behaving right. He was an African named John and while he pretended to be tough with the prisoners, he helped the main character in his attempt to escape. He was killed by the computer for that reason.

I don't even know if this was a series or just a movie, they were always showing in TV the same episode (not even the complete episode...) and I still wonder what was the outcome of this story!

It's been more than 20 years since I last saw this episode.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to see the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/), to see if there's anything else you can add to your question to make this anime more identifiable. For example - do you remember what TV channel was always showing this, 20 years ago? On a related note, what area/country were you seeing it in? Do you have a vague idea of how long you watched the parts you did see (may help identify if it was a episode of something vs. a movie).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guys thank you very much about your help. I tried to search it for one more time and.... I found it. It's the following anime called Savior of the earth:

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1454628/

At last!

Comment: Please explain why the answer fits (it helps other people find it in the future), then you can accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: How do you find out?

Comment: I started browsing in YouTube and watching some cartoons that I remembered they have been showed in the same period with this one. I was constantly checking the suggested videos by YouTube hoping that the recommendation would show the anime I wanted. After searching quite a bit, it was there!   The previous time I tried to search without any success for this anime was by typing the plot and hoping that there would be a page containing the plot. However this was not true, so after changing my search strategy I relied on the YouTube recommendations and bingoooo!

Answer (score 1):

the *dot hack* or *.hack* franchise included several anime series as well as games, etc.  At least one series involved one character "trapped" in an online game.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.hack[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.hack)

I haven't seen all of the series in the franchise so I don't know if any of them fit your description.  The first series first aired in 2002, at least four years after you say you saw the episode, so unless your date is incorrect it is probably not what you remember, but I thought I would mention it anyway.

The *Ghost in the Shell* franchise had the movie of the same name in 1995 and the first series in 2002.   I don't remember a plot such as you describe in what I watched but I didn't watch it all.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell)

Again, I suggest that this might be a possibility.

Comment: As someone who has watched all of GitS, I can assure you that no such plot exists in it.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the one that I am looking for. Thanks for answering! The one that I refer to seems to be really old, and to be honest I think that it might have been produced during the 90s

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [ReBoot](https://www.thetvdb.com/series/reboot)?

> The series follows the adventures of a Guardian named Bob and his
>   companions Enzo and Dot Matrix as they work to keep the computer
>   system of Mainframe safe from the viruses known as Megabyte and
>   Hexadecimal. The setting is in the inner world of a computer system
>   known by its inhabitants as Mainframe. It was deliberately chosen due
>   to technological constraints at the time, as the fictional computer
>   world allowed for blocky looking models and mechanical animation
>   <sub>Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReBoot)</sub>

It was a CGI animated series, four seasons long, and what you describe could possibly be the plot of a single episode.

Comment: Oops... I noticed that the OP already posted the correct answer only after posting mine... sorry

Answer (score -1):

I have not seen the anime, but just google your description... Is it Ai no Kusabi??

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ai_no_Kusabi

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to SFF ! Can you add a few details that suggest similarity? Link-only answers should have supporting details that summarize the content of the link. Please take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9444/how-to-write-a-good-story-id-answer) to help you improve your answer. Also, don't forget to take the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) ;)

Comment: No unfortunately this is not the one I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: If you would have read the wikipedia page, you should have been able to exclude this one from the list of possibilities :/

Comment: The good news is that I managed to find it eventually. I have updated the description!

Answer (score -2):

are you talking about [Sword Art Online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_Art_Online).

it sounds like what you are talking about. but this show is only about 10 years old.   So maybe there was something before.

Comment: It's definitely not Sword Art Online. It doesn't fit the time frame, there's no black guy named John, and I'm almost certain there's no Pac-Man game.

Comment: @F1Krazy you are probably right. I don't really remember much about sword art online.  but thought the concept was similar, just not some of the specifics, so thought perhaps I just remembered it even less than I thought.

Comment: No unfortunately it's not Sword Art Online. Thanks for answering anyway. I am trying to find this anime for years without any success. I guess that this will haunt me for more years!

Comment: Sword Art Online is 10 years old??